# Can anyone tell what does the number 33 mean in my lock screen of iOS 10?

Tags: ios, screen-lock, beta-seed-program

Recently, I tried iOS 10 public beta in my iPhone 6, but I am confused by the lock screen, see the picture, my question is what  the number 33 means in my lock screen?

[image: lock screen]

Update: In the new version of iOS 10 public beta 2, this confusion is no longer existed.

Comment: What is shown if you switch your iPhone to english?

Comment: @patrix my phone is in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This was an issue in early betas of iOS 10. The correct string in Chinese characters is displayed in Developer Beta 3/Public Beta 2.

**Original Content:**

The number is the current "year" in the current cycle of the [Chinese Sexagenary Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_sexagenary_cycle).

Year 33 of the current cycle corresponds to `丙申` in the Stem-Branch system, which is displayed when the date is displayed in the Calendar application (both iOS and OS X/macOS).

General formula for converting years 4 AD/CE and later is `floor(western year - 3)/60)`, where `floor` is equivalent to taking only the part in front of the decimal.

Example: `floor((2016-3)/60) = floor(2013/60) = floor(33.55) = 33`

See the link for more details on the system.

In iOS, previous versions may have displayed the long string which can be seen when opening the Day view of the Calendar app.

To enable/disable this display, go to `Calendar > Alternate Calendars` in the Settings app.